# How do I calculate a discrete Laplace Transform in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have a function in the time-domain that I'd like to transform to the s-domain. I'm not sure how to do this in Python.

I know that if I wanted to transform to the frequency domain, I could use something like this:

```
from scipy.fft import fft
data = np.linspace(0,10,100)**2
fourier = fft(data)
```

Which would provide a frequency space representation of the function.

Is there a similar Python function that transforms a time-domain signal to the s-domain?

Comment: What is your time-domain function here?

Comment: The array 'data' is supposed to represent a time-domain function. In reality, it could be anything. I'm just wondering how to transform a function to the s-domain in Python.

Comment: What is the "s domain"?

Comment: It's the complex frequency domain. Applying the Laplace Transform to a function of time, produces a new function of complex frequency, aka the s-domain.

Comment: A Laplace transform is typically applied to a continuous function, not to discrete data like you're showing here. You could try to fit a continuous function and then perform a Laplace transform on a symbolic representation of that using something like SymPy, but I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve here, other than asking if something is possible? If it were possible (which it isn't without substantial effort and within certain restrictions), what would you want to do with the result?

Comment: What Grismar suggests seems good. If you know exact function that formulates `data`, you don't need to use SymPy, you can just calculate transformation integral on paper or with wolframalpha. You will get recipe for Laplace transform in S-domain and you can do whatever you want with this, for example evaluate values for some complex grid.

Comment: could you throw some data at us to play with? `linspace**2` is kinda unruly. what do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Region_of_convergence provided that, a numerical approach will be very reasonable. I've been playing with functions from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms and they look spot on, if you grant deviations near s=0. I'm not formally educated in this stuff but my code for `L{sin(t) * u(t)}` and s=0 agrees with the integral of sin(t) e^0 dt (more or less, it doesn't converge, violating the criterion), while the given equation `omega / (s^2 + omega^2)` deviates from what would make sense. oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recipe. It's really just turning the math into numbers.

I did not pay attention to execution efficiency. If there's a "fast" Laplace transform like there is a *fast* Fourier transform, I wouldn't know, but that doesn't mean anything.

Nor did I pay attention to good numerical integration practices. This is just summing things up.

```py
t0 = -10.0
t1 = +10.0
dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(t0, t1, dt)
index_of_t = lambda t: int((t - t0)/dt)
# index of t = 0
it0 = index_of_t(0)

def laplace_transform(f, t, s):
    """given f(t), compute L{f}(s)"""
    Lf = np.empty(len(s))

    for i, si in enumerate(s):
        # Lf[i] = scipy.integrate.simpson(y=f * np.exp(-si * t), x=t)
        integrand =  f * np.exp(-si * t) * dt
        integrand = integrand[it0:]
        Lf[i] = np.sum( integrand )

    return Lf

alpha = 0.3
omega = 2.5
f = np.exp(-alpha * t) * np.sin(omega * t) * (t >= 0)

s = np.arange(0, 5, 0.001)
Lf = laplace_transform(f, t, s)
```

The rest is exercise.

Be aware that this stuff has "convergence" criteria. `s=0` means `exp(0) = 1`, so your data for s=0 is supposed to be integrated to infinity. Can't integrate a finite signal to infinity, so you can guess there will be differences near `s=0` if your signal isn't decaying to 0. Inspect those situations manually. You'll see that the numerics are right.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Region_of_convergence

One interesting example, the exponentially decaying sine wave, `exp(-a * t) * sin(w * t) * u(t)`, [taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms)

The function:

[image]

The numerical Laplace transform and what the Wiki article says it should be:

[image]

Here's a notebook with more plots:

https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/8a5a73eb836f7b0c8c2291a236327dc0